# How-to add preface into book generated by Python Sphinx from reStructred files set

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a set of rst  files that should be combined into one book (PDF or HTML)
for example

Preface.rst
Chapter1.rst
Chapter2.rst

etc.

Chapter file starts from header like:

## Chapter 1

Preface starts from header too.

## Preface

After generation by command :  sphinx-build ${build_options} -b latex "${src_dir}" "${target_dir}/pdf"

I see TOC with  item :

- Preface in document body that has header Chapter 1
- Chapter1 in document that has header Chapter 2
  etc.

I would like

- Preface in document body **without additional header Chapter 1**
- Chapter1 in document that has header Chapter 1

etc.

What way is able to help me to reach this target